# How to convert a csv list (horizontal) from vertical name value pair set

Tags: regex, jedit

I have a list like this:

```
GTPYANJ         695848
GTPYANJ         27811
FPORTAL3        432532
```

I want to turn it into this using regular expressions:

```
GTPYANJ,695848,27811
FPORTAL3,432532
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Seems to me that would be a lot easier by not using regular expressions.

Comment: My suggestion: don't use regular expressions.

Comment: This is for a one-time report where writing some code would be overkill.  Otherwise it'd be simple to read it and populate a hashtable and use that.

Comment: Even with regular expressions, this would require multiple passes.  You are best off writing a quick script to do this.

Comment: perl -e 'while(<>) { chomp; ($tag, $num) = split /\s+/; $tmp{$tag} .= ",$num"; }  foreach $t (sort keys %tmp) { print $t.$tmp{$t}."\n" } '  myfile.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load into jEdit (or Notepad++, or some other editor that can search/replace via regex.

Step 1 is to make sure that the delimiter is a tab.

Then, search for

```
^(.*)\t(.*)\n\1
```

and replace that with

```
$1\t$2,
```

Repeat the find/replace all until no more matches are found.

Comment: This of course only works for your very particular file.  If you throw in any extra white space, or your list is not sorted, this will break miserably.  Not to mention, if you have thousands, or even hundreds of entries, you are stuck repeating the search/replace manually, because I am not aware of any search replace that starts over at the beginning indefinitely until there are no matches left.

Comment: Good point.  For my one-off data manipulation task it worked great.  As a programmatic solution it would need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner:

```
perl -e 'while(<>) { chomp; ($tag, $num) = split /\s+/; $tmp{$tag} .= ",$num"; } foreach $t (sort keys %tmp) { print $t.$tmp{$t}."\n" } '  myfile.txt
```

Much easier than trying to hobble together a multi-pass regex that will most likely break a couple of times before you get it right, and which depends on the data being sorted, and which might require a second regex to reformat everything at the end...